# Yii2 delete all rows based on an equal to condition and a not in condition

Tags: yii2

Here I am using [Yii2](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/index.html) for developing an application. It is slightly different from Yii1. During the development, I am just stuck on a point that I need a delete functionality for an area.
For deleting some rows from `DB` I am using [deleteAll()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-activerecord.html#deleteAll()-detail) method like the following:

```
Model::deleteAll(['not in', '<attribute_1>', $attribute_1_values_array]);
```

It is working fine for me. But now I want to append another condition to this delete function like:

```
<attribute_2>=<attribute_2_value>
```

I know we can use `where()` for adding conditions with `delete()` and then I tried it with this `deleteAll()` method. But it didn't support.

Here I need to combine both `not in` condition and `equal to` condition in the same query.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 9):

here is how I usually do this :

```
\common\models\Record::deleteAll([
    'AND', 'status = :attribute_2', [
        'NOT IN', 'id',
        [1, 2]
    ]
    ], [
    ':attribute_2' => 'new'
]);
```

and the result is :

```
DELETE FROM `record` WHERE (status = 'new') AND (`id` NOT IN (1, 2))
```

Comment: Okay. Let me try this one :)

Answer (score 4):

You can remove `[]` brackets from `deleteAll()` function and use like this.

```
Model::deleteAll('attribute_1 NOT IN :attr_1_value AND attribute_2 = :attr_2_value', ['attr_1_value'=>$attribute_1_values_array,':attr_2_value'=>$attribute_2_value]);
```

OR

```
Model::deleteAll('attribute_1 NOT IN '.$attribute_1_values_array.' AND attribute_2 = '.$attribute_2_value);
```

Removing `[]` will allow adding standard/custom `query`.

Answer (score 4):

You can delete all records as below :

```
Model::deleteAll(
          ['AND',
            ['NOT',['attribute_1'=>$attribute_1_values_array]],  // array i.e [1,2]
            ['attribute_2'=> $attribute_2_value ]
          ]
        );
```

Compact way :

```
$condition = ['AND',
  ['NOT',['attribute_1'=>$attribute_1_values_array]],
  ['attribute_2'=> $attribute_2_value ]
];

Model::deleteAll($condition);
```